# CSS animation of ravens flying in a circle

Tags: performance, css, html5, animation, sass

I just made a little [experiment on codepen with this animation](https://codepen.io/1conu59/full/dVwQoW/).

But I get some performance issues: sometimes it's not as smooth as it should be.

Does someone know some practice I could use to improve it?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+Great+Primer");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#poem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
  font-family: "IM Fell Great Primer", serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1pt;
  word-spacing: 1pt;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#ravens-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  *width: 100%;
  *height: 100%;
  *border: solid 1px black;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: turn 20s linear infinite;
}

.ravens {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  *border: dotted 1px black;
  background: url("https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/42/2/1508268549-crow-sprite.jpg") left center;
  animation: sprite 0.7s steps(4) infinite;
  transform: rotate(var(--a, 0deg)) translateY(-220px);
}
.ravens:nth-child(2) {
  --a: 30deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(3) {
  --a: 60deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(4) {
  --a: 90deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(5) {
  --a: 120deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(6) {
  --a: 150deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(7) {
  --a: 180deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(8) {
  --a: 210deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(9) {
  --a: 240deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(10) {
  --a: 270deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(11) {
  --a: 300deg;
}
.ravens:nth-child(12) {
  --a: 330deg;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  100% {
    background-position: -400px;
  }
}
@keyframes turn {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="poem">
  <div id="ravens-circle">
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
    <div class="ravens"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Huginn and Muginn</p>
  <p>Ravens black</br>On wings of night</br>Nine worlds circled</br>In their flight</p>
  <p>One-eyed Father</br>Hears their call-</br>Tidings brought</br>To Asgard's hall. </p>
  <p>Thought as fast</br>As lightning's flash.</br>Mem'ry old</br>As sacred Ash. </p>
  <p>Huginn and Muninn</br>See and hear.</br>Whisper all</br>In Odin's ear.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In which browser(s) and on which platform do you have performance issues? I tried this in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on macOS and it was always very smooth.

Comment: I'm on chrome right now, it's smooth but every 5 seconds I've some frames dropping... I catched it with chrome dev tool perfomance section every 10 seconds it drop from more than 60 to less than 30 fps.